# Multiple actions for true (or false) in JS ternary shorthand syntax?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I have been picking up JavaScript recently, and was wondering what the proper syntax would be for setting multiple variables for each outcome in a shorthand ternary.

Here is an example of what I currently have, a shorthand ternary that changes 1 variable if a condition is met, and changes 1 other variable if it is not.

```js
var numberA = 5;
let rltvToTen = '';
let otherVar = '';

numberA >= 10 ? rltvToTen = 'EqualOrGreater' : rltvToTen = 'Less';

console.log(`Relative to ten: ${rltvToTen}`);
```

What I'm wondering is how I could make this so that if numberA >= 10, it would still set rltvToTen to the string 'EqualOrGreater' but would, in that same step, set otherVar to the string 'Lorem Ipsum.'

For example, for condition?ifTrue:ifFalse, I want to set multiple actions to occur for ifTrue

(Note: I'm aware that other tactics could be applied, but I'm genuinely curious as to whether there is a proper syntax that allows multiple actions set to occur given a condition back-to-back in the shorthand form.)

(Another note: I'm towards the end of the day and running on my last braincell, so I don't doubt I may have phrased this in an unnecessarily confusing way, and I'm sorry for that.)

I tried just putting the actions back to back.
I tried , and ; to separate multiple actions.
I tried using a space to separate multiple actions.
I tried reading the [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator).

The answer to this is likely right in front of me, but I probably just can't see it cuz I'm a skiddie newgen lmao.

Comment: This is just advice from experience: "wanting" to use a particular language feature because it is appealing in some way is kind-of perverse. Write clear, easy-to-read code whose intentions and logic are clear. There's nothing wrong with an `if` statement.

Comment: use the `()` (grouping operator) - though, I too would advise against that in favour of easy to read code - especially considering I would write that ternary as `rltyToTen = numberA>=10 ? 'EqualOrGreater' : 'Less'` instead of the way you wrote it

Comment: @JaromandaX It was actually brackets, but thanks for setting me on the right track!

Comment: As for the concerns about being easy-to-read, I am currently programming for leisure and I can read it fine myself. If I ever pursue this as a career, I will use easier-to-read formats such as if statements.

Comment: `It was actually brackets` - no, it was definitely grouping operator that I suggested that would work

Comment: @JaromandaX Well, when I ran it with parenthesis, it thought I was trying to call the previous action as a function. When I ran it with brackets, it worked fine.

Here's what worked for me:
```var numberA = 12;
let rltvToTen = '';
let otherVar = '';

numberA>=10?rltvToTen='EqualOrGreater'[otherVar='loremipsum']:rltvToTen='Less';

console.log(`Relative to ten: ${rltvToTen}
other variable: ${otherVar}`);```

Comment: which results in `Relative to ten: undefined other variable: loremipsum` ... so, yeah - fail - whereas the grouping operator `(rltvToTen = 'EqualOrGreater' ,otherVar = 'loremipsum')` works as you would like

Comment: but the way I would do it if a gun was held to my head to make me use ternary for this would be `let rltvToTen = numberA >= 10 ? (otherVar = 'loremipsum', 'EqualOrGreater') :'Less';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this only because there's a really bad answer - which, despite protestation, does not work in ANY javascript environment, if you must do this, do it like this

using grouping `()` and comma `,` operators

```js
var numberA = 12;
let otherVar = '';
let rltvToTen = '';
numberA >= 10 ? (otherVar = 'loremipsum', rltvToTen = 'EqualOrGreater') : rltvToTen = 'Less';
console.log(`Relative to ten: ${rltvToTen} other variable: ${otherVar}`)
```

Though a more concise method is:

```js
var numberA = 12;
let otherVar = '';
let rltvToTen = numberA >= 10 ? (otherVar = 'loremipsum', 'EqualOrGreater') :'Less';
console.log(`Relative to ten: ${rltvToTen} other variable: ${otherVar}`)
```

But as mentioned in the comments, there's nothing wrong with `if` for easy to read and understand code

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Sorry for being so insistent about my wrong answer being right. I genuinely misread it and thought it was, LOL 

I guess this is a sign I need sleep.

Comment: @gideoncalv ... or coffee

Answer (score 0):

You could always return and destructure an array of values to *one-line* the assignment

```js
const numberA = 5;

const [rltvToTen, otherVar] = numberA >= 10 ? ['EqualOrGreater', 'loremipsum'] : ['Less', ''];

console.log({ rltvToTen, otherVar });
```

```js
const numberA = 12;

const [rltvToTen, otherVar] = numberA >= 10 ? ['EqualOrGreater', 'loremipsum'] : ['Less', ''];

console.log({ rltvToTen, otherVar });
```

Comment: Wish I could add multiple answers, this answer solves both the concerns of brevity and readability. Thanks!